# Any way to get Time Machine to backup to Amazon Simple Storage Solution?

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine

Just curious if it is at all possible to have Time Machine backup to the 'cloud' using Amazon Simple Storage Solution. I've setup Time Machine to work over the network before to unsupported volumes (NTFS) but wasn't sure if this is possible. Anyone ever tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Dolly Drive](http://www.dollydrive.com/) is newly-announced software that lets you do TimeMachine backups to "cloud storage". Their docs say the space is their own cloud-based storage space, not S3, so that might be sticking point. But other than that it's pretty much in line with what you're after.

In addition to doing the TimeMachine -> cloud bridge, they also help you duplicate your data to a local drive so you can do fast restores without having to wait for delivery of an cloud -> hard drive dump of your data.

Looks promising. I'm lukewarm on the pricing.

Comment: Well, it seems they're not supporting Time Machine anymore.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an extra ec2 instance, you could use netatalk and s3ql. It is a native time machine solution and works in Lion too. Your backups will be compressed and deduplicated.

From Ubuntu:

#### Install S3QL (1.11.1) and netatalk (2.2.1)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nikratio/s3ql

sudo aptitude update

sudo aptitude upgrade

sudo aptitude install s3ql netatalk
```

#### Create S3QL authfile

```
mkdir ~/.s3ql
vi ~/.s3ql/authinfo2
```

#### Edit S3QL authfile as follows:

```
[s3]  
storage-url: s3://  
backend-login: $AWSKey  
backend-password: $AWSSecretKey
```

#### Set permissions on authfile

```
chmod 600 ~/.s3ql/authinfo2
```

#### Create S3QL filesystem

```
sudo mkfs.s3ql s3://$bucketName
```

#### Mount S3QL filesystem

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/$bucketName
sudo mount.s3ql --allow-other --nfs --compress lzma s3://$bucketName /mnt/$bucketName
```

#### Configure netatalk

```
sudo vi /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default
```

#### Edit the bottom of AppleVolumes.default to appear as below:

(Note: tm is also added to :DEFAULT: options. Volsizelimit is in MiB#
:DEFAULT: options:upriv,usedots,tm

```
/mnt/$bucketName  "S3 Backups"  volsizelimit:238418.58
```

#### Create User for backup

```
sudo useradd $username
sudo passwd $username
```

#### Set ownership of the backup drive to the backup user

```
sudo chown $username /mnt/$bucketName
```

Then select Go -> Connect to Server -> and enter the server IP or hostname from the finder. Make sure you have port 548 open!

Answer (score 5):

There is a FUSE-based project calles [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) that claims to be able to mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a local volume. Since Time Machine seems to be able to use any locally available volumes as a target, this should work. I was not able to test this, however.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'd seen it but was hoping someone else had tried this before (I guess I can be the guinea pig this time). Cheers!

Comment: @jstarek: so does that mean time machine can backup to your idisk?

Comment: TimeMachine has all kinds of trouble sync'ing to non-HFS+ formatted shares. I know I went through hell and back trying to get remote TimeMachine backups to an SMB share, shared out from my Windows server. I gave up after a time. I'd like to hear if anyone's successfully used a FUSE-mounted drive for a TM backup.

Comment: @Ian me also, I'm going to give it a try today and see where I get but would love to hear if anyone else has had any success!

Comment: @Ian @Kevin, I was wondering if you managed to get this up and running and if you encountered any issues?

Comment: @mrwooster I can't keep the MacFUSE drive connected during the initial (long) file transfer to S3. Keeps dropping, then TM bails. Same problem I had with local SMB backup

Comment: @mrwooster I had major issues as well. In addition, I'm not sure how I would do a restore from the operating system installation menu (which scares me). At this point I think that Dolly Drive (see post below) is the best option.

Comment: @Ian @Kevin, I have been reading a bit more about this and it looks like a lot of people are having problems.  Additionally, dolly drive is actually about 1/3 the price of using S3! I think that its going to be the better (and far simpler) solution.  Thanks for the feedback tho.

Answer (score 4):

A different approach would be to use a local Time Machine backup and then use something like [Arq](http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/) to move it to the cloud (automatically). You get the benefit of local storage + cloud backup.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about doing something like this but ultimately wanted a backup solution that wouldn't require me connecting to an external hard drive or time capsule. I'd like something that works on the road, etc. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: The only downside to this approach is you have to detect and active TimeMachine backup in progress before you do the sync. Otherwise you might be sync'ing a filesystem that's not in a steady state.

Comment: @Ian it's possible to avoid this sort of "clipping" if you program TM and Arq to do it at certain hours. But yes, this requires a local storage anyway.

Comment: @Kevin as an alternative you can use Arq directly :) (I do) You lose the benefit of "time" machine, but you have a backup in the cloud :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get Time Machine to recognize a FUSE-mounted filesystem, then [s3backer](http://s3backer.googlecode.com/) should work.

I have never done this but would be interested to hear if anyone gets it to work (specifically how they got Time Machine to recognize the mount).

See also [this wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/s3backer/wiki/MacOSHints).